# Is there way to get field lookup Id from Visualforce Page in Apex?

Tags: controller, salesforce, apex, visualforce

Is there a way to get the label Id as shown in the Elements box. Lookup Id is fine, that we can get it but to get the Label Id of "Loan" ?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Well, that `<label>` doesn't have `id`, it only has `for` that couples it with `<input>` field. You want that `<input id="...">`? What are you trying to do? rename the field with JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.  It has `for`. I was trying to auto-populate the `Id` of the contract when a new user clicks on the new button. Like when you have a master-detail relationship and you want to create a new object then the `Id` of the master record is automatically populated. Now, I have created a Visualforce page and on click of the `New` button, I want to auto-populate some lookups with Ids aka Name.

Comment: Now, let say you got the Id in Apex Controller then assigning that Id with the name will auto-populate the value. let say the URL is `https://sales--dev.my.salesforce.com/a2g/e?CF00N0l00000WER2=LAI-00000ZSS&inline=1` Assigning `CF00N0l00000WER2` with the Name of the field `LAI-00000ZSS` will actually work. but the problem is getting the `<input id="...">` dynamically in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: To auto-populate lookup with Name as soon as the user clicks on `New` button

**Approach**: If you get the Field Definition Id of the lookup then assign the DurableID with the populate lookup Name.

**Query to get DurableID** :

`1.List<FieldDefinition> fieldDefiInstance  = [Select  DeveloperName,label,Id,DurableId,EntityDefinitionId From FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.DeveloperName='Party' and label = 'Contract'];`

`2.String fieldKey =fieldDefiInstance[0].DurableId.replace(fieldDefiInstance[0].EntityDefinitionId+'.','')+'CF';`

`3.System.debug('fieldKey=>'+fieldKey);`

Got Id as `CF00N000000XXX`. Now assign `CF00N000000XXX=ContractName` in the url
Example: `https://sales--cldev.my.salesforce.com/XXX/e?**CF00N000000XXX=ContractName**&inline=1`

**The Result:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It won't work that way. What you described in comments is often referred to as "URL hacking". On standard pages like "new", "edit" it works - but it works based on `<input name="blabla">`, not `<input id="blabla">`.

Look at this: https://www.google.com/?q=hello

Inspect the field's source - there's `name` but no `id`. And yet I prepopulated the field.

Since it's a Visualforce page - you have control over the URL parameters. You can make something like `/apex/vfPageName?contractId=....`, you don't have to try to be smart about the `CF00N0l00000WER2`. And then in the Apex constructor you can use `ApexPages.currentPage.getParameters().get('contractId')`.

I don't know what controller you have in there. Just `<apex:page controller="MyClass"` or `<apex:page standardController="Contract" extensions="MyClass"`. The 2nd one will let you read id of the record for which the button was clicked, but if you need more params passed via url - look into that `getParameters()`

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69808/get-current-page-query-string-parameters-in-apex

If you **really** need the ids... They're in form of "CF" (custom field) + field Id as seen in setup when you view the field definition. You can query the Ids for example in FieldDefinition table. But for what you need - looks like we'd be over-complicating stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not actually looking for `getParameters()` data. your last line is what I needed. I need to get a FieldDefinition table. I was able to do it.  I will write my answer as 'Answer my Question.